# How do I setup IdentityServer AllowAnonymous actions that uses my webapi? (WebApi with MVCClient and IdentityServer4)

Tags: c#, identityserver3, identityserver4

I have an IdentityServer, a Web Api and an MVCClient that will eventually be a SPA. (.Net Core 2)

My MVCClient has a mix of Authorized and non Authorized actions (or pages). I was able to successfully call and get a token (server to server) from the IdentityServer and validate that it works. Using the following lines which is based off of the example they have provided.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> CallApiWithClientToken()
        {
            var discovery = await DiscoveryClient.GetAsync("http://localhost:<myport>");

            // request token
            var tokenClient = new TokenClient(discovery.TokenEndpoint, "inventoryApp", "mysecret");
            var tokenResponse = await tokenClient.RequestClientCredentialsAsync("invAPIScope");

            var client = new HttpClient();
            client.SetBearerToken(tokenResponse.AccessToken);
            var content = await client.GetAsync(_apiUrl + "/testidentity/get");

            if (!content.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                return new JsonResult(tokenResponse.Error);
            }
            else
            {
                return new JsonResult(content.Content);
            }

        }
```

*First problem:* 
**But** once I try and get the token and follow the flow of the above code, *using postman*, it would throw an **'Unauthorized'** error. I'm not sure what's wrong with the call. It seemed straight forward that I just get a token from the authorization option (of postman) and then do a get call to the endpoint.

My goal is, I have a page (AllowAnonymous) on my MVCClient that I plan on using React with. This page does not require logged in credentials but will make calls to my Api (AllowAnonymous). But I want to make sure that the api is protected by a token that was generated for the mvcclient. So the api can't be used by other third applications not registered on my IdentityServer.

I looked at sample projects provided by the IdentityServer team and that's where I based all my codes from. I'm not sure if I missed anything on their examples. I didn't see any examples that would require a token to make an api call for a public page (allowanonymous) on the mvcclient side.

**EDITED to make it a little clearer**

Answer (score 0):

`AllowAnonymous` Attribute which negates the Authorize Attribute and allows anonymous access to your actions. But in your case you want your api call to be protected by a token

> This page will make calls to my Api.. But I want to make sure that it's protected by a token that was generated for the mvcclient.

I guess you need to make sure the user is logged in before making this call.